# Get JAR compilation time

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf, compilation-time

I am trying to get the compilation time of the runnable JAR file I am exporting from Eclipse. One way to do this would probably be to get the modification time of the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to get this information (I know how to read the manifest itself using `getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`, but I can't seem to be able to read its modification time).

Has anybody some insight on how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, based on Aleks G's answer and others found elsewhere, I came up with a more robust solution (that e.g. works also on network shares):

```
public static Long getTime(Class<?> cl) {
    try {
        String rn = cl.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
        JarURLConnection j = (JarURLConnection) cl.getClassLoader().getResource(rn).openConnection();
        return j.getJarFile().getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF").getTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I was hoping for a better way to go from the Class object to the resource name but I guess this will have to do.

Comment: You might want to replace `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(rn)` with `cl.getClassLoader().getResource(rn)` in case the class was not loaded using the system classloader

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to the jar file itself, you should be able to read the jar file using `java.util.jar` package, then get `ZipEntry` for the Manifest file and use `getTime()` on it to get its last update time.

```
JarFile jf = new JarFile("myfile.jar");
ZipEntry manifest = jf.getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
long manifestTime = manifest.getTime();  //in standard millis
```

If you need to deal with the specific class, then you may find this code also useful;

```
String rn = this.getClass().getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(rn).getPath();
String jarFile = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("!"));
```

Then `jarFile` will contain the path name of your jar.  Note that if the class is not loaded from the jar file, then the third line will fail, as `path.indexOf` will return -1.

Comment: Sure, but this breaks horribly if the jar is renamed. Can I get a reference to the actual JarFile my main class is being loaded from?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to get that through the classloader object.

Comment: @CAFxX I updated my answer to show how to get the name of the jar file having the class.

Comment: Almost there. The problem is that the `path` variable won't contain an absolute path (when run from a jar file), but only the relative path inside the jar itself (i.e. something like `com/strayorange/test/test.class`). This means the following line will inevitably fail.

Comment: @CAFxX That would be rather strange.  As you're requesting the load path of the resource straight from the classloader, it should know the full path of the jar file.

Comment: jarFile is prefixed with "file:".  You need something like jarFile = jarFile.replace("file:", "") to get rid of it else the new JarFile() will fail.